# EntityListener preUpdate prePersist not called

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using doctrine event listeners a lot, but this is my first entity listener.

```
class ReportListener
{
    /** @ORM\PreUpdate */
    public function preUpdate(Report $report, PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
    {
        $report->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->logger->debug('UpdatedAt ' . $report->updatedAt->format('c')); // I get *NO* log !!!

        $this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet(
            $this->entityManager->getClassMetadata(Report::class), $report); // is this necessary?
    }

    public function prePersist(Report $report, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $report->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->logger->debug('UpdatedAt ' . $report->updatedAt->format('c')); // not called!
        $this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet(
            $this->entityManager->getClassMetadata(Report::class), $report); // do I need that?
    }

    public function postUpdate(Report $report, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // IS CALLED !!!!
    }

    public function postPersist(Report $report, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // IS CALLED !!!
    }
}
```

#

So, it should just update the updatedAt timestamp...
My entity is standard:

```
@ORM\Table(name="report")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"App\EventListener\ReportListener"})
 */
class Report {...}
```

I am using this in a symfony context, I even registered every event explicitly, but no luck.

```
report_listener:
    class: App\EventListener\ReportListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, event: preUpdate}
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, event: prePersist}
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, event: postUpdate}
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, event: postPersist}
```

another question is if I really need to recompute the change set in PrePersist and preUpdate...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, because you are not updating your entity before `prePersist` / `preUpdate` you do not need to recompute it.

Secondly, you do not need annotations for your service listener. Please read this documentation for more information. I think is pretty clear what you should do: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#listening-and-subscribing-to-lifecycle-events

Comment: I want to use an **EntityListener**, no event listener. Even without the annotations, preUpdate and prePersist are not called, but postUpdate and postPersist are called.

Answer (score 0):

Recently i've had a problem like this, after implementing a new entity listener, my symfony 2 app would not call it and this bugged me for about and hour or so, and it all came to clearing doctrine metadata first after implementing the changes to entity listener, even in my dev env.

```
app/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```

In my dev env i had to **clear the metadata even after implementing a new function** that didn't exist in an already existing entity listener class.
From my experience you do not need annotations in the entity listener class when the function uses the default names like postLoad - preFlush - preUpdate - postUpdate etc. And if the entity listener class needs some services loaded a service declaration like bellow is enough.

```
    app.entity_listener.check_cif_changes:
    class: App\MainBundle\EventListener\CheckForCifChangesListener
    arguments:
        - '@services.send_mail_helper'
    tags:
        - {name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener, lazy: true}
```

Also some more info i've documented about entity listeners:

- events order on entity creation: prePersist - preFlush - postPersist
- events order on entity Update: postLoad - preFlush - preUpdate - postUpdate
- events where flush is safe to use: postPersist - postUpdate

The clear metadata command changed in symfony 3+

```
bin\console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
```